# Address Not Required (PayPal)

Tags: html, forms, button, paypal, payment

I'm using the older  PayPal buttons to sell digital goods, so no postal address is needed.
By PayPal's recommendation, the value (form below) should be set to "1" but if I use that, the buyer still gets presented with an off-putting address required box.
I've managed to get rid of the address box by using "true" but, there's no sales, so does this value="true" affect the running of the rest of the code and PayPal accepting the payment?
I've tried it myself on a penny sale and it's been OK, but I have all the cookies so it's bound to go through OK.
I'd be grateful for any thoughts on this please.

```
<input type="hi**dden" name="address_override" value="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass address_override; use no_shipping with value "1".

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables